# Create custom function for hero image

Tags: functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm newbies with php development and I want create a custom functions

I would like to create a function that calls an image which has the same name as the product  but I fail to call the product name and then place it in the image name. Could you help me please.

my code :

```
add_action('init', 'custom_hero_image');
function custom_hero_image() {
    $result = get_the_title( 'ID' );
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $html .= '<img class="jarallax-img" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/inc/assets/img/shop/hero/'.$result.'.jpg">';
    } else {
        $html = '<p>No results found.</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_title()` returns the post (product) title including all HTML, whitespaces and symbols not allowed in URLs, etc. Use post slug instead.

Also, you don't need to use any actions.

```
function custom_hero_image( $post_id ) {

    $product = get_post( $post_id ); 
    $slug    = $product->post_name;

    if ( is_product( $post_id ) ) {
        $html = '<img class="jarallax-img" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/inc/assets/img/shop/hero/'.$slug.'.jpg">';
    } else {
        $html = '<p>No results found.</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

And call the function within a template file:

```
<div id="hero">
    <?php
        // get the post ID outside the Loop
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        // print the <img>
        echo custom_hero_image( $post_id );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this allowed me to solve my issue but also to understand my errors and thus to be able to code other functions ! 